# Avoiding redundant code using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to devise a tkinter gui, that, among others, lets users choose a 'working folder' and a 'destination folder (and there is more coming). I stripped the code to its bare functionality hereunder.

I found myself duplicating code for the selection of both the 'working folder' and the 'destination' folder. I came up with the solution to put these variables in a dictionary (I could pass them as mutable objects along with the lambda). Although it is a working solution, I have the feeling there is more standard way of achieving this objective.

My question therefore is: how can I make my `_browsefile()` function work whilst changing the value of `self.working_dir` and `self.destination_dir`, without using an artificial dictionary structure, hence avoiding duplicate code? This would implicate that I can generalize the `_browsefile` func somehow.

I have seen very advanced reusage features in text books, but currently this is out of my league. If I can learn to tackle this 'easy' one, it would possibly help me on my journey.

Thank you for giving me advice in doing it the Pythonic way...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

class View():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.gui_variables = {'working dir': '',
                              'destination dir': ''}
        
        self.menu()
    
    def menu(self):
        self.folder_button1 = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Choose Working Folder",
                                       command=lambda: self._browsefile(self.gui_variables['working dir']))
        self.folder_button1.pack()

        self.folder_button2 = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Choose Dest. Folder",
                                       command=lambda: self._browsefile(self.gui_variables['destination dir']))
        self.folder_button2.pack()


    def _browsefile(self, directory):
        answer = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.gui_variables[directory] = answer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    View(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a dictionary. You can just refer to the attrs of a class by their name. Something like:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from typing import Optional


class View:
    def __init__(self, parent: tk.Tk):
        self.parent = parent
        self.working_dir: Optional[str] = None
        self.dest_dir: Optional[str] = None

        self.menu('Working', 'working_dir')
        self.menu('Dest.', 'dest_dir')

    def menu(self, title: str, attr: str):
        def browse():
            setattr(self, attr, tk.filedialog.askdirectory())

        button = tk.Button(
            self.parent,
            text=f'Choose {title} Folder',
            command=browse,
        )
        button.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    View(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Notes:

- Do not add a `()` suffix to your class
- Do not assign those buttons as members on your class
- Centralize the creation of the buttons and the associated command
- For the command handler, use a simple closure
- To target a specific member variable, accept a parameter that's used with `setattr`
- Use type hints

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my code and for the additional advice.

Comment: What's wrong with using `()` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud it's a Python 2 construct, not needed these days

Comment: @Reinderien Oh okay, thanks for replying.